# curl_exec not working in SDKs but curl works in command line

Tags: php, curl, ssl-certificate

We're hosting a website on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance. Our PHP version is 5.3.29. We haven't upgraded to 5.4 because some of our code is not forward compatible. Our curl is currently version 7.38.0. After a software update, we began having issues with the curl_exec command in a couple of our PHP SDKs. The curl command on the command line still works fine. The two SDKs we're having an issue with are the Facebook and Mandrill SDKs. We were also having issues with the Amazon S3 SDK, but I found the solution on SO of adding

```
'scheme' => 'http'
```

to the S3 object parameters and it took care of the problem. This one was generating a CurlException in Guzzle.

Searching over Stack Overflow I've seen posts on setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false, but that hasn't helped the other two SDKs.

Both SDKs throw CurlException 77, "error setting certificate verify locations". This seems to indicate that curl can't find the SSL certificate files, but I checked the permissions on the certs folder, and they're 755 and owned by root:root, so I believe this means they should be accessible. I also tried setting CURL_CAPATH to the directory where my certs are located, but that didn't help either.

For Facebook curl_getinfo gives the following values:

```
array(22) { ["url"]=> string(45) "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token" 
["content_type"]=> NULL 
["http_code"]=> int(0) 
["header_size"]=> int(0) 
["request_size"]=> int(0) 
["filetime"]=> int(-1) 
["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) 
["redirect_count"]=> int(0) 
["total_time"]=> float(0.00424) 
["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.004197) 
["connect_time"]=> float(0.019219) 
["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0) 
["size_upload"]=> float(0) 
["size_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_download"]=> float(0) 
["speed_upload"]=> float(0) 
["download_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["upload_content_length"]=> float(-1) 
["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0) 
["redirect_time"]=> float(0) 
["certinfo"]=> array(0) { } 
["redirect_url"]=> string(0) "" }
```

and for Mandrill:

```
array(22) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(59) "https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/template-name.json"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.004241)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.004194)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.005479)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I noticed that certinfo for both here is false, which again seems to indicate a certificate problem. I'm not sure what that certificate problem is, though. Is there a CURL option I need to set so that curl can find the certificates?

Comment: Hm, have you updated `ca-certificates` (at least: that's how the package is called in Debian/Ubuntu) lately? If not: try it. If I read my google-fu correctly, this error also occurs if it's certificates are out of date, not only if they're not available.

Comment: php-curl is just wrapper. Maybe you can use exec() or shell_exec() for receive response body?

Comment: @Wrikken Good thought. I'm assuming this can be done through the server package update and not going somewhere and downloading the latest versions and uploading them, right? I tried yum update ca-certificates and got the response that no packages were marked for update, though.

Comment: [for yum based systems this might be of interest](http://serverfault.com/questions/394815/how-to-update-curl-ca-bundle-on-redhat)

Comment: @Wrikken Thanks for the link. I tried the curl command updating the bundle from curl.haxx.se and that didn't help, though, and then I dropped ca-bundle.crt into ca-trust/anchors and ran update-ca-trust and that didn't work either. Is there a way to tell whether your certificates need updating?

Comment: Hm, I only know that for .pem's: `openssl x509 -in somename.pem -text` shows all the info you need of a cert. Are you sure BTW every directory _above_ the CA path also has r-x enabled so the user can read it? Can the user as your application runs as do a simple `file_get_contents()` on those? And, as a final resort: did you read the changelogs of relevant packages (openssl, curl) you updated?

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, @Wrikken . I did test out a simple PHP script that was able to pull the contents of ca-bundle.crt, so that looks OK, and the expiration date in ca-bundle.crt was 2018, so that's good too. The only .pem file I have is a link pointing to ca-bundle.crt. I looked for change logs, and the only one I found was yum.log, which did indicate that both openssl and curl were changed in the last update, although I can't say what the changes were. I googled to try to find where package-specific logs might be but no luck. Are these something I would have had to set up myself?

Comment: I usually work on `apt` based systems, so I'd have to google. There _is_ a yum-changelog package, can you try that one?

Comment: @Wrikken This has been fixed. It was taken care of by recompiling the curl library. Thank you for all your suggestions and guidance here.